# Node Js - AWS signal: aborted (core dumped)

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda, graphql, apollo-server, prisma-graphql

I'm new to AWS lambda, I have a simple app using Node Js + Prisma + Apollo, for front end I'm using react, my lambda function it was working fine a couple of weeks a go, but I was trying to update a new version of my static site and I found this issue:

```
Error: Runtime exited with error: signal: aborted (core dumped)
Runtime.ExitError
```

this is my lambda file:

```
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    endpoint: '/dev/graphql',
  },
  context: ({ event, context }) => ({
    headers: event.headers,
    functionName: context.functionName,
    event,
    context,
    prisma,
  }),
});

exports.serverHandler = server.createHandler({
  cors: {
    origin: '*',
    credentials: true,
  },
});
```

I already try to increase `timeout` and also the `memory` but still not working.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution for this issue ?  also happening to me :(

Comment: Yes, what I did was https://gist.github.com/brulio93/994b1538eb94507f1d356ec055185302 the image upload was causing the problem, you can try with the code that I share with you in the gist. Hope it help!  @PersianIronwood